# Strings as If/else results

Tags: vba, excel

This line of VBA works when I use integers for my results, but it fails when I use strings. What is the fix?

```
Cells(3, 17) = _ 
    "=IF(COUNTIF('\public\Documents" & _
    "\Amazon Retail\Analysis\" & _
    "[US Retail Quick Reference.xlsx]" & _
    "Quick Reference'!$A:$A,$P3)>=1," & _
    "AmazonRetail","AmazonUS")"
```

Comment: All `"` inside the string needs to be doubled `""`; `...,""AmazonRetail"",""AmazonUS"")"`

Comment: Also technically you want `Cells(3, 17).Formula = ...`

Answer (score 0):

Try swapping out the double quotes with single quotes within the total formula.

```
Cells(3, 17) = "=IF(COUNTIF('\\public\Documents\Amazon Retail\Analysis\[US Retail Quick Reference.xlsx]Quick Reference'!$A:$A,$P3)>=1,'AmazonRetail','AmazonUS')"
```

I don't get the same error with this code, but I can't tell if it really works because I don't have the source document used in the formula.  I hope that helps!

Comment: It is really good that you want to help. But you do not need `'\public\Documents\Amazon Retail\Analysis[US Retail Quick Reference.xlsx]Quick Reference'` to make it work. You may try to build up something with your own path, it will follow the same rules. Once you do it, you would see that you need `""AmazonRetail""` in doubled parenthesis and `Cells(3, 17).Formula`. This way you learn :)